# DNS Forwarders based on Source IP Addresses(Bind 9)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Sites A,B  ---> Site C (Win2012R2 DNS Server) --> forwards external DNS queries to our "BIND Server" (where DNS forwarders are set) when surfing the Net.

Our clients in both Site A and Site B relies on Site C's DNS server for internal DNS resolution.
Since Site A and Site B are from different places, I would like to have separate DNS forwarders based on IP addresses of Sites A and B, which are then to be set in the Bind Server to improve the performance.

Is it possible to achieve that? Or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Win2012R2 DNS Server but with Bind9 you can achieve what you want pretty easily with Bind9 `acl` + `views`

Define two `acl` to match each site based on source address

```
acl siteA {
    10.1.1.0/24;
    fde1::/64;
};

acl siteB {
    10.2.2.0/24;
    fde2::/64;;
};
```

Then define two `views` based on `acl` and for each `view` define `forwarders` you want

```
view "siteA" {
    match-clients {
        siteA;
    };
    recursion no;
    forwarders {
      8.8.8.8
      2001:4860:4860::8888
    };
};

view "siteB" {
    match-clients {
        siteB;
    };
    recursion no;
    forwarders {
      8.8.4.4
      2001:4860:4860::8844
    };
};
```

This setup works perfectly, usually relevant for **internal** / **external** zones. For example allow recursion for internal clients and act as authoritative name server for external clients

Comment: any other settings required? I have tested the configuration using a client from site B. From the log it shows "view siteB: query (cache) 'xxxxx.local/A/IN' denied." I did a nslookup and "query refused" error occurred. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are trying to resolve an internal name ```.local```, the zone should be handled by Win2012R2 DNS Server. Is BIND the first server receiving the query ? Do you want to forward the query to windows or do recursion to resolve it ?